# VS Code with Modern Fortran linting across files

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

I am running VS Code on Windows with the Modern Fortran extension. I have installed fortls (not fortran-language-server, but fortls). I also have the mingw toolchain with gfortran.

I have a fortran project with source code across several files (most in the same directory, but for now we can consider them all in the same directory)

Almost everything seems to work correctly "across files", eg :

- Autocompletion is configured to use fortls (which is the default anyway), and will suggest functions that are defined/coded in another file of the project
- Hovering is configured to use fortls as well (again, the default), and hovering over a function call will display an overview of how it should be called, even if said function is in another file
- Right-click->Go to Definition will open a tab and point me to the relevant code section, even if that is in another file

Static syntax analysis seems to work fine for anything that can be checked inside a given file. For example, if I have a function *f* coded in file A.f, and somewhere else in A.f try to call *f* with the wrong number of arguments, the editor adequately signals an error.

But if the same function *f* from A.f is called from another file B.f in the same directory, then the same errors won't be caught and no error is signaled by the editor. They will only be caught and signaled for calls made inside the same physical file.

I am not sure what to do to remedy this. I have added the following to the VSCode settings.json file, but to no effect

```
    "fortran.linter.includePaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
    ],
    "fortran.linter.modOutput": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/linter",
    "fortran.fortls.suffixes": [
        "f"
    ],
    "fortran.fortls.directories": [
        "./**"
    ],
    "fortran.fortls.preprocessor.suffixes": [
        ".f"
    ],
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Compilers often do not catch this kind of error unless link time optimizations are used. Moder Fortran has modules that enforce the explicit interface.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks for the reply ! It indeed seems like the compiler itself is not catching this error. Would you know how to enforce this ?

Comment: In modern Fortran programming we use modules. It is also possible to create a module that contains interface blocks to certain external procedures. But you are probably looking for a way to enforce this in the codebase you have. In Intel Fortran there is the `-warn interfaces` flag included in the generic `-warn`. That option actually generates interface blocks for you.  Gfortran also detects this problem when the called procedure is in the same file, but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I am using gfortran. gfortran actually does sometimes recognize such errors, even if calls are not being made from the same file, and sometimes it doesn't (just found out about this, I will update the question). So actually it looks like this probably is a gfortran issue...

Comment: If you are using modern Fortran (not 77)  you use function prototypes.  It does rely on the prototypes being correct but if you put them in an include file instead of having them inline in the code, then they will be consistently right or consistently wrong.